# Sorting algorithm with 10 elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have to make a program that asks the user to input an array of `10` elements with numbers from `0` to `9`.

Then the array is sent to the function. This function will sort each number in the array as follows:

[image: sort]

I don't know how to reposition the numbers.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know how to swap the numbers around or you don't understand what the question is asking? The question is asking that you take the index of each position in the array and match is with a value. The first index is 0, but there is no matching value in the array, so place in the element marked by index 0 a value of 0. The next element is 1, so try to find a value of 1 in the array, if you find it, place it at the element marked by index 1 or if not, place a 0 there. The next index is 2 etc, etc. follow on through the whole array like this.

Comment: The function does not involve only sorting. There are other set of operations to be performed on the array to get the desired output. `What you can do is to ask the question mentioned in that link over here and also go through `http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve``

Comment: I understand the question, but I don't understand how to approach the problem.

Comment: If you don't know how to swap the elements, read a basic C book first. If you don't know how to sort, a simple google search will give you the result right away, along with tons of sorting ways on stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! `out`being initialized to 0, `for(i=0;i<10;i++){out[in[i]]=in[i];}` this question is not about sorting anything. [And it is about doing homework, so it is off topic. Unless you have tried something...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of 
[Joel Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4293798/joel-gregory)'s comment:

This function creates an unedited array, copies original's contents to it, then loops from first index to last. It will be used as the basis of checking for any matches for the indexes.

In each iteration, the function searches the unedited array if any of it's elements matches the index number. If yes, it replaces the initial value to the index value. Else, zero is assigned. And so on until the last index.

```
 void swap(int *original, int max_elements) {

      int index = 0, matcher = 0, unedited[max_elements];

      // copies original to unedited
      memcpy(unedited, original, max_elements * sizeof(int));

      for (--index; ++index < max_elements; ) {

           // searches the original array for matches with the current index
           // loops until it finds a match or it reaches the maximum number of elements
           for (matcher = 0; unedited[matcher] != index && ++matcher < max_elements;);

           // if there is match, the initial value is changed with it's index value, else zero is the new value.
           original[index] = (matcher != max_elements) ? index : 0;
      }
 }
```

**Output:**

```
Original: 1 1 7 8 2 8 1 6 3 2 
Sorted:   0 1 2 3 0 0 6 7 8 0
```